# mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have (note: username and password are made up):

```
const CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb+srv://smith_bob:smith_bob@hotmail.com:T@llyHo!:@cluster0.r92qc.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(()=>app.listen(PORT,()=> console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`)))
    .catch((error)=> console.log(error.message));
```

but get the following when I run *nodemon index.js*:

> mondodb+srv URI cannot have port number \
> [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart

Any ideas what's going on?

I tried using Percent Encoded characters but got errors as follows:

`. . . smith_bob:smith_bob@hotmail.com:%40@llyHo!: . . .`

> mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number

`. . . smith_bob%3Asmith_bob%40hotmail.com%3AT%40llyHo!%3A . . .`

> bad auth : authentication failed

`. . . smith_bob:smith_bob%40hotmail.com%3AT%40llyHo!: . . .`

> Password contains unescaped characters

`. . . smith_bob:smith_bob@hotmail.com%3AT%40llyHo!: . . .`

> mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number

Answer (score 9):

Seems like it's because of the presence of multiple `@` and `:` prior to the host `cluster0.r92qc.mongodb.net` without percent encoding. Try to provide it in the following format:

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@host
```

If the username or password has any one of `: / ? # [ ] @` characters, it must be converted using [percent encoding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.1).
Taking your connection string for example, **if** the username is `smith_bob:smith_bob@hotmail.com` and password is `T@llyHo!:`, it should be converted to `smith_bob%3Asmith_bob%40hotmail.com` and `T%40llyHo!%3A`, respectively, and the connection string would become:

```
"mongodb+srv://smith_bob%3Asmith_bob%40hotmail.com:T%40llyHo!%3A@cluster0.r92qc.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

To read more about the Connection String format, refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/connection-string/).

Comment: Many thanks. I tried to use Percent Encoding, but still got errors. I edited the Original Post to include the errors I received. Is my Percent Encoding somehow incorrect? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I was facing the same issue but then I updated my password and it worked.

If anyone want to avoid this jargon then while creating users Atlas, use option of 
`Auto Generate Password` which will avoid this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try percentage decoding as mentioned in the previous post. For me, it worked.
if user_name is `user` and password is `user@` then `mongodb+srv://user:user%40@cluster0.r92qc.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

where %40 is percentage encoded for @ in the password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).