# Unable to connect with mongodb using Nodejs Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working with nodejs/express js,Right now trying to run "existing project" (downloaded from github) in my local machine,But right now i am getting following error

```
MongoDB connection error: MongoParseError: mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number
```

In "mongodb atlas"(dashboard),here is my "connection url" (replaced username and password)

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@orbitXXXX.huykolo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

And here is my ".env" file,Where i am wrong ?

```
# MongoDB
DB_CLUSTER = "mongodb+srv://XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXX@orbitXXXX.huykolo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
DB_USER = "XXXXXXXXXX"
DB_PASS = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69290528/mongodbsrv-uri-cannot-have-port-number

Comment: @hassansuhaib how can i "encode/percent encode" username and password ?

Comment: You can find information about Percent Encoding here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1. You can also find information about Connection String URI Format here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/connection-string/

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75841334/12215015).
Hope it helps.