# mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working with nodejs,using express js,Right now i am getting following error

```
MongoDB connection error: MongoParseError: mongodb+srv URI cannot have port number
```

In "mongodb atlas"(dashboard),here is my "connection url" (replaced username and password in "url encoded" format)

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@orbitXXXX.huykolo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

So i passed my "username"(email) and "password" in my ".env" file, And here is my ".env" file,Where i am wrong ?

```
# MongoDB
DB_CLUSTER = "mongodb+srv://XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXX@orbitXXXX.huykolo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
DB_USER = "XXXXXXXXXX"
DB_PASS = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Here is my index.js code

```
const username = encodeURIComponent(process.env.DB_USER);
const password = encodeURIComponent(process.env.DB_PASS);
const clusterUrl = process.env.DB_CLUSTER;
const authMechanism = "DEFAULT";

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@${clusterUrl}/?authMechanism=${authMechanism}`;

export const dbConnect = mongoose
    .connect(uri, {
        dbName: 'git_flow',
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        pkFactory: { createPk: () =>  new UUID().toBinary() },
        useNewUrlParser: true
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.error('Connection error', e.message)
    })

export const db = mongoose.connection;
export default mongoose;
```

Comment: Shouldn't cluster string (`DB_CLUSTER`) only contain `orbitXXXX.huykolo.mongodb.net`? Right now, this env variable contains whole connection URL.

Comment: @kriplerm what should i do ?

Comment: Does your password contain a colon `:` and/or and ampersand `@`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes my password contain "@"

Comment: @kriplerm understand your point! but now i am getting following error
"Connection error Protocol and host list are required "

Comment: Ok, maybe your `DB_CLUSTER` was good, but then your username and password in this env variable should be url-encoded too.

Comment: @kriplerm my username and password already url encoded

Comment: In .env file too? Unless you have already changed your posted code, why are you encoding them in JS file then?

Comment: Have you tried to use same connection URL as in Atlas, i.e. something like ``const uri = `mongodb+srv://${encodeUriComponent(process.env.DB_USER)}:${encodeUriComponent(process.env.DB_PASS)}@orbitXXXX.huykolo.mongodb.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority}`;`` ?

Comment: Why do you define username/password twice? I guess `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@${clusterUrl}` is resolved to `"mongodb+srv://XXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXX@mongodb+srv://XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXX@orbitXXXX.huykolo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"` which would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constructing URI in index.js file, you can mention it as an environment variable.

.env file -

```
MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXX@orbitXXXX.huykolo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Now use this URI directly to connect with database. Also don't forget to install `dotenv` package to be able to load the environment variables from the .env file.
index.js file -

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

export const dbConnect = mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        dbName: 'git_flow',
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        pkFactory: { createPk: () =>  new UUID().toBinary() },
        useNewUrlParser: true
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.error('Connection error', e.message)
    })
```

If it still doesn't work, try changing the password for the database user.
Go to MongoDB Atlas and you must see *Database Access* tab under the Security Heading in the side menu -
[image: side menu of the MongoDB atlas homepage]

Click on *Database Access* and you must see a user entry in the list.

[image]

Click on edit and then change the password, copy it, and don't forget to click the **Update User** button at the bottom.

Carefully replace the username and password in the MONGO_URI and it should work.